# Missing Number Picture Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[image: Can you solve this Puzzle?]

This is is logical reasoning puzzle in which your challenge is to find the relationship among the given numbers and then find the value of the missing number.
Source: https://www.funwithpuzzles.com/2017/07/mind-blowing-math-questions.html

Comment: The question is answered on the source page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is 9 because 6*6+3=3*10+9; 3*3+5=1*10+4; 5*5+4=2*10+9

Comment: It took a while for me to verify that your answer is correct (which it is), but I think you need to provide a better explanation of why instead of just the formulas.  e.g.  "top left squared + top right = bottom left * 10 + bottom right"